# Is there a valid proof of one-to-one correspondence b/n the real interval $(0, 1]$ and the nonterminating decimal expansions $0.d_1 d_2 d_3 …$?

Tags: real-analysis, alternative-proof, decimal-expansion

As per Michael J. Schramm, 1996, Introduction to real analysis, Theorem 6.6:

In an Archimedean ordered field in which the Nested Intervals property holds, there is a one-to-one correspondence between the interval $I = (0, 1]$ and the nonterminating decimal expansions of the form $0.d_1 d_2 d_3 …$

The proof is based on nested intervals and uses a procedure with infinite number of steps.

Is there known way to proof this theorem not using infinite procedure?

7/23/2022

It seems my question needs some clarification.

I was looking into multiple textbooks for real analysis, and there were a few that made the effort to prove the equivalence of these two sets. Most were just mentioning about it, almost like an axiom. And since by definition the decimal real number is an infinite string of digits, there is always an infinite procedure involved that would map the real number to the string. The procedure itself in some sources is described explicitly, like in Michael J. Schramm, in some it is assumed implicitly.

Let have as an example how the problem is treated in Introduction to Real Analysis by Jirí Lebl, 2018.

Let's consider only real numbers in the interval $I = \left(0, 1\right]$. Take an infinite sequence of
decimal digits $0.d_1 d_2 d_3 …$ where there is a digit $d_j$ for every $ j \in \mathbb{N}$ and define

$D_n := \frac {d_1}{10}+\frac {d_2}{10^2}+\frac {d_3}{10^3} + ... + \frac {d_n}{10^n}$

as the truncation of $x$ to $n$ decimal digits. We say then that this sequence of digits represents a real number $x$ if

$x = sup \{  D_n : n \in \mathbb{N} \}$.

${Proposition \; 1.5.1}$

i) Every infinite sequence of digits $0.d_1 d_2 d_3 … $ represents a unique real number $x \in [0, 1]$, and

$D_n \leq x \leq D_n + \frac {1}{10^n}$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$

ii) For every $x \in (0, 1]$ there exists an infinite sequence of digits $0.d_1 d_2 d_3 …$ that represents $x$.

If following relation holds:

$D_n < x \leq D_n + \frac {1}{10^n}$ for all $n \in  \mathbb{N}$

then the representation for $x$ is unique.

The proof of the first part follows directly from the definition.

The proof of the existence is based on the Archimedean property and uses strong induction.

The procedure how to define the next digit is not shown explicitly, it is just proven that there exists integer $j$ such that

$(j - 1) 10 ^{-(n+1)} < x - D_n \leq j 10^{-(n+1)}$

The uniqueness, again, follows from the definition and the conditions:

$D_n < x \leq D_n + \frac {1}{10^n}$ for all $n \in  \mathbb{N}$

which in fact states that all the digits $d_n$ are uniquely defined by the procedure above.

What is my problem with that kind of proof - first, it involves an infinite number of steps, as well as conditions, and second, in order to verify any of the conditions one needs to have a way to compare $x$ to the current truncated value $D_n$. Obviously, $D_n$ is a decimal number, but what is $x$?

The whole proof looks like a Gedankenexperiment. Is that a valid proof?

Comment: Your concrete question is not clear to me from what you've written. It would be easy to answer your questions curtly, but that is probably not what you are looking for: "(...) what is $x$?" -- $x$ is the real number for which you are proving that a decimal representation exists -- "Is that a valid proof?" -- yes.

Comment: @Mees de Vries - Thanks for noticing my question. Sure I know that $x$ is a real number, but what is its presentation? I do not have a way to compare an abstract $x$ to a decimal in order to do any calculation. But the bigger problem to me is that the proof for uniqueness imposes infinite number of conditions. And your answer is, yes, it is OK to have infinite number of conditions, this is a valid proof?

Comment: The exact meaning of "$x$ is a real number" depends on the definition of real numbers that your book is using; it might help to refer to that. The infinite sequence of steps amounts to a [recursive definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_definition), which is justified by induction.

Comment: @Karl - Yes, it is a recursive procedure and it is justified by induction (in this case strong induction). Assuming that the first $n$ steps are done, the $(n+1)$-th step is: 

Find an integer $j$ such that following relation holds

$(j - 1) 10 ^{-(n+1)} < x - D_n \leq j 10^{-(n+1)}$.

Then the $n+1$ digit of the expansion $d_{n+1} := j - 1$

About the meaning of $x$, the author defines it as $x \in \mathbb{R}$ where 

$x = sup \{  D_n : n \in \mathbb{N} \}$, having $D_n$ the truncation of $x$ to $n$ decimal digits.

Comment: But I can't see how that definition would help me to define the numeric value of $j$ above. In fact, the $x$ defined this way is the final result of the recursive procedure, when you have already calculated all the digits $d_n, n \in  \mathbb{N}$.

That's quite different from the construction of the reals, where the real numbers emerge either from Cauchy sequences or Dedekind cuts of rational numbers only.

Comment: Hmm, but you follow the proof that at each step a unique $j$ exists satisfying the conditions for that step, right (using the Archimedean property)? And you agree that a sequence satisfying a recursive definition like this can be proven to exist (and to be unique) by induction? I'm confused about what your worry is.

Comment: Maybe you're missing the overall structure of the proof? $x$ is a given fixed real number and we're defining the digit sequence based on it (not the other way around).

Comment: Re "I do not have a way to compare an abstract x to a decimal in order to do any calculation": you don't need to do a calculation - we know that the reals are totally ordered, so any two are comparable. Using this fact (and others), we're establishing that every real number has a certain property (namely that a corresponding decimal sequence exists). It's abstract and non-computational because that's the way we've described $\Bbb R$.